# Page template suggestion per language?

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

How can I add page templates for different Languages in my Drupal 6?

For example, if I want to make different page template for Bulgarian language, **page-bg.tpl.php** doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A drupal.org groups [comment](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21165) shows examples how to allow use of multiple tpl.php file versions.

Using

```
<?php $vars['template_file'] ?>
```

it is possible to create your own template file suggestions.

Example:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

  if($vars['language']->language == 'bg') {
    $vars['template_file'] = 'page-bg';
  }
}
```