# Multi language with different layout drupal 6

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site with English and Spanish. I need to change the Layout(theme) of my English pages but no chnage in spanish pages. Can we have separate tpl file based on Language? Any help will be appreciatable

Answer (score 0):

John,

This question has already been answered here:
  [Page template suggestion per language?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14884/page-template-suggestion-per-language)

Cheers,